# Removing records with email address from sync

Tags: marketing-cloud

I need to remove records that are coming in from the MC connect sync. We already have everything established, but I just need to remove the records without email addresses coming in from Sales Cloud. Can I do this without disconnecting my current connection? I haven't been able to find a way to do it without disconnecting and would prefer not to disrupt current services if possible.

Any insights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to remove records coming from SF within Marketing Cloud is not a good idea. A much better solution is to never sync those records to begin with.

To accomplish this, all that you need to do is to go into Contact Builder > Data Sources > Synchronized > Your SF org > The Object you want to not sync null emailaddress from.

Then, look in the the bottom left hand corner for the "Configure Synchronization" card and select "Edit". Then you can update the criteria within "Records Collection" to only sync records where your field for email address is not null.

[Here's the documentation that references this.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_creating_and_interacting_with_synchronized_data_sources.htm&type=5)

Comment: You need to delete the contacts using the contact delete process after you modify the sync settings

Comment: @EazyE thank you for clarifying that bit. It's definitely important that you remove everything you've already synced after this modification.

Comment: How can you identify the right people to delete through the process? Is there a good walk-through of the contact delete process? I've ran into issues where contacts are not completely deleted after going through what I thought was the proper method. @EazyE

Comment: Use this help doc  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Permanently-remove-Contacts-or-Subscribers-and-associated-data-from-Contact-Builder&language=en_US&type=1